# How to create an if-else statement depending on time intervals in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Right now my app has a timer that runs in seconds. I would like the code to work as this. By the time the timer reaches 10 seconds, display image `A`, else display image `B`.

```
if green {
  timer.invalidate()
  startStop.isEnabled = true
  scoreTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateScoreTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: So just set the image (whichever image you're talking about, not that I would know, because you didn't post any meaningful code) to image a, and start a timer that sets the image to b after 10 seconds

Comment: Why are you rescheduling the timer each time?  Use a repeating timer and decrement or increment a counter variable. The use the value of the counter to determine which image to display

Answer (score 3):

Set `imageA`.  Use a scheduled timer to set `imageB` in 10 seconds:

```
imageView.image = imageA
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { _ in
    imageView.image = imageB
}
```

**Note:** Using `Timer` with a block is only available on iOS 10 and newer.  If you are supporting older iOS versions, you will need to use the version that takes a *selector*.

---

If your `updateScoreTime` routine is called every second and does more that just manage the images, you can keep a count of the number of seconds in a property:

```
imageView.image = imageA
scoreTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateScoreTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
count = 0
```

When the timer pops:

```
func updateScoreTime(_ timer: Timer) {
    // update score time
    ...

    // change picture if >= 10 seconds
    count += 1
    if count >= 10 {
        imageView.image = imageB
    }
}
```